# ステップワイズ法によるBCsFt集団のQTL解析

Tags: r

ステップワイズ法によるQTL解析を行うときに以下のエラーが出てしまいます。

```
No default penalties available for cross type bcsft
```

cross type bcsftでモデルを構築するにはどうすればよいのでしょうか。
調べてみましたがわかりませんでした。よろしくお願いいたします。

> mapFunc <- "kosambi"
> data <- read.cross("csvr", >file="Bc1F4.csv", estimate.map=T, >map.function=mapFunc, BC.gen=1, F.gen=4)
> --Read the following data:
> 114  individuals
> 23  markers
> 73  phenotypes
> --Estimating genetic map
> --Cross type: bcsft
> data.sim <- sim.geno(data,step=5, >n.draws=128, map.function=mapFunc)
> gr.sw <- >stepwiseqtl(data.sim,pheno.col="gr", max.qtl=2)
> stepwiseqtl(data.sim, pheno.col = "gr", max.qtl = 2) でエラー:
> No default penalties available for cross type bcsft

Comment: cross type bcsft、Rなどをタイトルに含めたりタグに含めるなど、環境が一目でわかるようにしたほうが良いかもしれません。

Answer (score 0):

ゲノム解析?の分野には全く詳しくないので, あくまでプログラミングの範疇で (エラーが出ないかどうか) の回答になります:

こちらでは提示されたコードを再現できない (参照されているデータがない, そもそもRの構文的におかしい箇所がある) ので, 想像で補った以下のコードを試したところ, 最後に同様のエラーが発生しました.

```
require(qtl)
mapFunc <- "kosambi"
datweb <- read.cross("csv", "https://rqtl.org/sampledata", "listeria.csv", estimate.map=T, map.function=mapFunc, BC.gen = T, F.gen = 4)
data.sim <- sim.geno(datweb, step=5, n.draws=128, map.function = mapFunc)
gr.sw <- stepwiseqtl(data.sim, pheno.col = 1, max.qtl = 2)
```

エラーメッセージに書かれているように, penalties を設定したところエラーが出なくなりました. ただしQTL解析のことはわかりませんので, この値が適切なのかは私にはわかりません.

```
gr.sw <- stepwiseqtl(data.sim, pheno.col = 1, max.qtl = 2, penalties = 1:3)
```